# amCharts: Always show 0 on value axis and enable negative velues to be displayed

Tags: amcharts

I have got this silly problem.

I am creating a simple serial chart, displaying columns for two simple data series. The values are quite clse to eachother so amCharts decides to hide the 0 value axis and dislay only the relevant data. This is all good, but the thing is that I need to be able compare my columns visually. I also want to hide the labels on the value axis at some point.

Generally what I get now is this:
[image]

As you can see, value axis starts counting from 22.5. I need it to always start counting from 0, so I can compare the columns relatively to each other in a visual way. I know I can set the `minimum` propert of the value axis to 0 to achieve my desired result. But when I set any of the values to be negative, it does not display on the chart.

This is what I get with the `minimum` property set to 0 and one of the data points set o a negative value:

[image]

Here is a demo of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/gregzx/scyhwws4/1/
`minimum` set to `0` and one of the values set to a negative value.

Summing up: I need to always display the 0 value on the value axis AND be able to display negative values. Any hints will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a negative value for the minimum setting as well. As an example, you could set your minimum value to -30 and the maximum setting to 30.

This also makes sure that the 0-line is in the vertical middle.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [{
    "minimum": -30,
    "maximum": 30
  }],
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at work and just solved it perfectly, You need to determine if there are any negative values in the incoming chart data, and of course, you want to avoid all negative values, so you also need a Boolean value to determine if the values are all negative.

Here's how I did it:

```
// your chart component
const XXXChart = ({ chartData }) => {
  const hasNegative = chartData.some((it) => it.value < 0)
  const allNegative = chartData.every((it) => it.value < 0)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ...

    valueAxis.min = 0  // set with zero, assume that chartData defaults to positive values
    if(hasNegative){
      valueAxis.min = undefined  // when there are negative and positive values, valueAxis.min will be restored to undefined, because valueAxis.max is undefined by default, and then chart will automatically set zero line.
      valueAxis.max = allNegative ? 0 : undefined  // When all values are negative, valueAxis.max can be set directly to zero
    }

    ...
  }, [chartData])
}
```

This is the perfect solution to your current problem.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that you also need to add a property that launches on valueAxis, `valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true`